# Convert float result to type double

Tags: android, parsing, math, double

I have coded this simple app to do seperate calculations on a users input.This is my calculation class where the calculations are passed to two variables:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 
            String getoffsetdepth = offsetDepth.getText().toString(); 
            String getductdepth = ductDepth.getText().toString(); 

            double tri1,tri2;
            double marking1,marking2;

            double off1 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetlength);
            double off2 = Double.parseDouble(getoffsetdepth);
            double off3 = Double.parseDouble(getductdepth)
                    ;
            marking1 = Math.pow(off1,2) + Math.pow(off2,2);
            tri1 = (float)off2/(float)off1;
            tri2 = (float)off3/Math.atan((float)tri1);
            marking2 = (float)off3/Math.atan(tri2);


            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalcResult.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("number1", marking1);
            myIntent.putExtra("number2", marking2);
            startActivity(myIntent);


        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Must enter a numeric value!");

        }

    }
```

In my calculation  result class I convert the results to double where they are represented in the text boxes.I'm wondering is the another way to convert the result as they seem to be float numbers or the calculations are off.

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double mark1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
        double mark2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);

        //set the variables on EditTexts like this :

        result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);
        result1.setText(mark1+"");
        result2.setText(mark2+"");
```

The resulting calculation isn't what I was expecting:

1.What I input:

https://plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/En1Bueexoc7

2.Resulting calculation:

https://plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/ApqinYrp8Na

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking.  Please simplify this question with an example of what you expect, what you get, and the calculation used to return the result you are not expecting.  All the rest of the code is just noise.

Comment: What are you expecting to get?  You could use casting to convert: double dbl = (double)theFloatVarHere;

Comment: @NormR Surely casting a double to a float is meaningless?

Comment: Yes, it was a poor attempt to answer a poorly asked question. A double to a float would go this way: float flt =(float)aDoubleVarHere;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're casting all your doubles into floats when you are calculating by using `(float)`:

```
        tri1 = (float)off2/(float)off1;
        tri2 = (float)off3/Math.atan((float)tri1);
        marking2 = (float)off3/Math.atan(tri2);
```

remove all of these from your code then you are only ever dealing with doubles.

```
        tri1 = off2 / off1;
        tri2 = off3 / Math.atan(tri1);
        marking2 = off3 / Math.atan(tri2);
```

Hopefully that does the trick! :)

Comment: Okay,I was under the impression that the these math function required float type variables..I'll give this a go :)